# Setting a property to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, entity

I have an entity which has property Person person(user defined object) so I wanted to setProperty("person", new Person()) however got an IllegalArgumentException "....Person is not a supported property type". It is a simple class with field String name and String country which implements Serializable.

> class People{ Person person; }

I am trying to:

```
entityOfTypePeople.setProperty("person", new Person());
```

this is where I get "IllegalArgumentException ....Person is not a supported property type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are always String objects (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html and http://leepoint.net/notes-java/io/30properties_and_preferences/10properties.html) as far as I know.  I think you want to use java preferences not java properties (though to be fair, I don't know if GAE supports that or not).

Comment: I had to make a call to DAO to do the setting and put(). I guess app engine's low level api does not support setting of an attribute for the entity other than common primitive wrappers.